# How is ++ defined on a large floating point

Tags: c++, ieee-754

So I've been looking at IEEE754 floating point double. (My C++ compiler uses that type for a `double`).

Consider this snippet:

```
// 9007199254740992 is the 53rd power of 2.
// 590295810358705700000 is the 69th power of 2.

for (double f = 9007199254740992; f <= 590295810358705700000; ++f){
    /* what is f?*/
}
```

Presumably `f` increments in even steps up to the 54th power of 2, due to rounding up?

Then after that, nothing happens due to rounding down?

Is that correct? Is it even well-defined?

Comment: Sorry, made the question clearer.

Comment: Things get weird with large/small floating points.  Floating point numbers have a limited amount of precision.  For extremely large numbers, `1` might as well be a rounding error.  For extremely small numbers, `1` is so large that it may "drown out" other digits.

Comment: The `++` operator for `double` is defined such that `++f` is equivalent to `f += double(1)`.

Comment: tmlen is right, compare: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=106

Comment: For suitably large `f`, `f + 1 == f`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - And for suitably small `f`, `f + 1 == 1`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2224579/103167  (and there's an exact duplicate I remember but am having trouble finding now)

Answer (score 4):

`++f` is essentially the same as `f = f + 1`, ignoring the fact that `++f` is an expression that yields a value.

Now, for floating point values, the issue of representability comes into play. It may be that `f + 1` is not representable. In which case, `f + 1` will evaluate to the nearest representable value to the true value of `f + 1`. In case there are two equally near candidates for nearest representable value, round to even is used.

This is covered in the [Operations section of What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#865):

> The IEEE standard requires that the result of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division be exactly rounded. That is, the result must be computed exactly and then rounded to the nearest floating-point number (using round to even).

So, if your example, for sufficiently large values of `f`, you will find that `f == f + 1`.

Comment: I think that your answer is not correct. here it's not the representability that comes into play, but the addition operation. In fact 1 is representable, f is representable (in the environment i tested it), the result is a double and is assigned to a double.

Comment: @AndrewBloom It's in the result of the operation that representability comes into play. When you have `x + y` then of course `x` and `y` are representable. The question is whether or not the true value of `x + y` is representable. When it is not, the IEEE754 standard decrees that the expression evaluates to the closest representable value to the true value. In my opinion, your answer's description of how arithmetic is implemented according to IEEE754 is not accurate.

Comment: said like that it seems that in the cpu you do the addition and have a register with the true arithmetic value as result, and convert that to a double after. I don't think that this happens though.

Comment: @AndrewBloom No, that's not how it is actually implemented. However, what is implemented is mandated to have the same effect as if you performed the exact operation, and then rounded to closest representable value.

Comment: @AndrewBloom For instance, refer to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html which says: *The IEEE standard requires that the result of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division be exactly rounded. That is, the result must be computed exactly and then rounded to the nearest floating-point number (using round to even).*

Comment: Let me firstly thank you to have given me the opportunity to learn something new. As it's written here, the subtraction (but i suppose then all the 4 operations), can be implemented computing the result in a quasi-exact way and then rounded to match the double precision.

Comment: "...computing the exact difference or sum of two floating-point numbers can be very expensive when their exponents are substantially different. That section introduced guard digits, which provide a practical way of computing differences while guaranteeing that the relative error is small. ...By introducing a second guard digit and a third sticky bit, differences can be computed at only a little more cost than with a single guard digit, but the result is the same as if the difference were computed exactly and then rounded [Goldberg 1990]. Thus the standard can be implemented efficiently."

Answer (score 1):

Being f++ the same as f = f + 1, as pointed out on the comments, and as i tested myself, f == f+1 (!!) for a large f dependent on the platform. An explanation is here (for small numbers, but the principle is the same) http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BinMath/addFloat.html

Here's how to add floating point numbers.

> First, convert the two representations to scientific notation. Thus,
>   we explicitly represent the hidden 1.  In order to add, we need the
>   exponents of the two numbers to be the same. We do this by rewriting
>   Y. This will result in Y being not normalized, but value is equivalent
>   to the normalized Y. Add x - y to Y's exponent. Shift the radix point
>   of the mantissa (signficand) Y left by x - y to compensate for the
>   change in exponent.  Add the two mantissas of X and the adjusted Y
>   together.  If the sum in the previous step does not have a single bit
>   of value 1, left of the radix point, then adjust the radix point and
>   exponent until it does.  Convert back to the one byte floating point
>   representation.

<strike>In the process of converting the number to the same exponent, due to precision, 1 is rounded to 0, and hence f == f + 1.</strike>

According to IEEE754, after the sum the number is rounded to match the double format, and due to the rounding operation, f==f+1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this loop will never end on rounding problem. I hope the reason is clear for you (since you are familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) but let me describe in short for impatient audience.

We can think about floating point as forced by compiler/FPU/standard special presentation of number. For simple example let's review:

- 20000
- 2e4
- 0.2e5

Both three forms represents the same number. Last two form called "science" form but what is the best? IEEE754 answers - the last one because we can save the space by omitting leading **0** and just write `.2e5` . Such decimal analogy is very close to binary presentation where there is a space for mantissa (`.2`) and exponent (`5`).

Now let's do the same for 20000.00000000001

`0.2000000000000001e5`

As we can see mantissa growth and there is some limit where fixed memory will overflow. Instead of exception we sacrifice precision, that (just as example) give as the `0.2e5`.

For bigger numbers (as in question) we have lost in precision too.

`9007199254740992` may be presented as `0.9e16` And when 1 is added nothing happens. 
So `f = f + 1` creates infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are problems where looping over large floating point values by increment of 1 is a meaningful solution, but people may be stumbling on this question looking for a workaround for their neverending loop. Therefore, even though the question only asks how the addition is defined by the standard, I'll propose a workaround.

Indeed, for large values of `f`, `f++ == f` is true, and using that as the increment in loop will have undefined behaviour.

Assuming it's OK that `f` be incremented by a number that is the smallest number `e` greater than `1` for which the floating point has a representation `f + e > f`. In that case, following workaround where the loop will always terminate could be OK:

```
// use template, or overloads for different floatingpoints
template<class T>
T add_s(T l, T r) {
    T result = l + r;
    T greater = std::max(l, r);
    if(result == greater)
        return std::nextafter(greater, std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
    return result;
}

// ...
for (double f = /*...*/; f < /*...*/; f = add_s(f, 1.0))
```

That said, adding tiny floats to huge floats will result in an uncontrollable cumulation of errors. If that's not OK for you, then you need arbitraty precision math, not floating point.